# Does a listen-only CGEventTap block event handling?

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I am writing a macOS tool that tracks statistics about key strokes. For that I create an event tap using `CGEventTapCreate` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454426-cgeventtapcreate)). Since my code does not alter events, I create the tap using the `kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly` option.

Do I still need to minimize the runtime of my event handling callback for fast processing of keyboard events? I assume that a listen-only handler does not block the event handling queue, but I can't find anything assertive for that in the documentation.

I read the API documentation and search the Apple Developer documentation archive. I did not yet profile event handling. I cross-posted this question to the Apple Developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734237

Answer (score 2):

I guess I could just have tested this before posting this question: kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly does not block the event handler queue.

I tested this by putting my event handler to sleep for 2 seconds, and it did receive but not block the other event handler.